# How to install the latest Ubuntu Shell theme under Ubuntu with vanilla GNOME

Tags: themes, 17.10, gnome-shell

I've installed the latest 17.10 Ubuntu and then used

```
sudo apt install gnome-session
```

to get rid of Ubuntu's modifications, as described [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/10/install-vanilla-gnome-shell-ubuntu-17-10).

Although I prefer to have a vanilla GNOME experience, Ubuntu's [new GNOME-Shell theme](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/09/ubuntu-17-10-gnome-shell-ambiance) is very appealing. Unfortunately, I can't find this theme in GNOME Tweaks. The only GNOME-Shell theme that is present there is GNOME's default one.

Does somebody know a convenient way to install Ubuntu's new GNOME-Shell theme?

Comment: Output of `ls /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme`?

Comment: `xxx@yyy:~$ ls /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme
gdm3.css                         ubuntu.css
gnome-shell.css                  ubuntu-high-contrast.css
ubuntu-checkbox-focused.svg      ubuntu-toggle-on-intl.svg
ubuntu-checkbox-off-focused.svg  ubuntu-toggle-on-us.svg
ubuntu-close-window.svg`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may load the default Ubuntu 17.10 shell theme from your home directory. To do that follow the steps below.

1. Create a directory, say `MyTheme` either in `~/.themes` or in `~/.local/share/themes`. (You may create `~/.themes` or `~/.local/share/themes` if they don't exist.)
2. Create another directory inside `MyTheme` called `gnome-shell`.
3. Create an empty document in this `gnome-shell` directory and name it `gnome-shell.css`.
4. Open this `gnome-shell.css` in a text editor and add the following line

   ```
   @import url("/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css");
   ```
5. Install and activate the **User themes** extension from [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/).
6. Install the indispensable  *(GNOME) Tweaks* (if not installed already) by running

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
   ```
7. Launch *Tweaks*, go to **Appearance** section and click on the drop-down box next to "*Shell theme*". **MyTheme** should appear in the drop-down list. Select it.

Comment: Awesome. This is what I was looking for. Changing the session's theme. I collected the css from ubuntu in my debian and created `gnome-shell.css` in Ambiance theme directory. The theme didn't appear in gnome-tweak-tool but I used gsettings to set the theme.

Comment: But gnome-terminal didn't followed the theme color. Could you add that method too?. 

Some components didn't change though. The slider of the volume icon didn't change

Comment: @Anwar I think I don't understand completely. Terminal theme/colour should not be dictated by the GNOME shell theme, but by the *applications* theme (GTK+). Perhaps you're looking for [something like this](https://askubuntu.com/q/971247)? And for the components like slider, checkbox etc. you need to get the image files (.svg files) also from the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/` directory along with the .css file. So better to copy the whole directory. Since you're copying this from one system to another, you may have to edit the .css file so that it contains correct paths to those .svg files.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry I wasn't clear enouogh. It's when you select "Use color from system theme", terminal colors follow system theme's scheme. That's not working.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the new Yaru gnome-shell theme shipped with Ubuntu 18.10, then `gnome-shell.css` file (refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/969667/480481)) should contain

```
@import url("/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css");
```