# Unity terminal in Ubuntu GNOME 16.04

Tags: themes, gnome-terminal, colors

I am using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 and my terminal looks like this.

[image]

Is there a way to get that purple background terminal like this?

[image]

Comment: I have tried colour combination in `preference` option but it doesn't look "good".

Comment: It would be easier to simply use the Unity desktop.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I'm using Gnome desktop and I like it. I don't want to use Unity desktop as of now.

Comment: I understand. I'm configuring Bash Terminal on Windows 10 to use Unity colours myself. It's more complicated...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Method 1: Change your GTK+ theme

Follow the steps below.

1. Install *(GNOME) Tweak Tool* and *Ambience theme* (if not installed already) by running

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool light-themes
   ```
2. Open Tweak Tool and go to  *Appearance*. Select "*Ambiance*" for application theme (or GTK+ theme).
   [image]
3. Launch *Terminal* and go to *Edit > Profile Preferences > Colours* (tab) (or something similar) and **check** the "*Use colours from system theme*" option.

**Note:** Ambiance is a global GTK+ theme, so it would make (almost) all the applications look "Unity-like", not just the Terminal.

---

#### Method 2: Change Terminal's colour profile

If you just want to change the colour of Terminal's background and font without changing your GTK+ theme, you may tweak Terminal's colour profile manually.

First load Terminal with Ambiance theme as suggested above and get hex codes of all the colours using some colour-picker application like `gpick`. You may install `gpick` by

```
sudo apt install gpick
```

Then switch to your preferred GTK+ theme (application theme), in Terminal's Profile Preferences **uncheck** the "*Use colours from system theme*" option and manually create a colour profile using the collected hex codes.

> #### Hex codes for Unity Terminal
>
> - `#300A24` - Background (Purple)
> - `#FEF8D9` - Text Colour (White)
>
>   (courtesy of [Rahul](https://askubuntu.com/users/563725/rahul))
>
> With the Hex codes provided above terminal looks something like this:
>   [image]
>   (screenshot courtesy of [Rahul](https://askubuntu.com/users/563725/rahul))