# Ubuntu 17.10 GNOME Shell Theme Color Sometimes Blue

Tags: gnome, themes, 17.10, gnome-shell

Not sure what's going on here. Sometimes when I boot up my (color theme?) is blue instead of the default orange. Other times its the normal orange.

[image]

[image]

I hate the orange and would like to make it always be blue and would also like to make my laptop always blue as well. Also my login screen on my desktop is still the old login screen and my laptop is the new one. No clue whats going on with my desktop and I can't get it figured out. I have no shell themes installed.

Ubuntu 17.10

GNOME Shell: 3.26.1

Current settings in tweaks/Appearance

Applications: Adwaita-dark

Cursor: DMZ-White

Icons: Ubuntu-mono-dark

Shell: (None) Default

Comment: I assume this is not a theme issue per se but something that is creating a translucent blue region like a draggable selection box malfunctioning and covering the whole screen with it. When this happened to me after resuming from sleep I just relogged and it went away.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're (inadvertently) switching between the (vanilla) "GNOME" session and the modified GNOME session titled "Ubuntu" ("Ubuntu" is orange, "GNOME" is blue).

You may load the "bluish" GNOME shell theme from your home directory. To do that follow the steps below.

1. Create a directory, say `MyTheme` either in `~/.themes` or in `~/.local/share/themes`. (You may create `~/.themes` or `~/.local/share/themes` if they don't exist.)
2. Create another directory inside `MyTheme` called `gnome-shell`.
3. Create an empty document in this `gnome-shell` directory and name it `gnome-shell.css`.
4. Open this `gnome-shell.css` in a text editor and add the following line

   ```
   @import url("/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css");
   ```
5. Install and activate the **User themes** extension from [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/).
6. Launch *Tweaks*, go to **Appearance** section and click on the drop-down box next to "*Shell theme*". **MyTheme** should appear in the drop-down list. Select it.

Comment: Switching from GNOME session to Ubuntu session from the lock screen does not change the colors at all on my desktop or laptop.
Desktop stuck with the blue theme.
Laptop stuck with the orange theme.
Also why is my desktop stuck with the old login screen?

Comment: @Blake Not sure why this is happening, but you should be able to manually set the "blue" theme following the steps in my answer (make sure you have the `gnome-shell.css` file in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/` first). Similarly you can manually [set the "orange" theme](https://askubuntu.com/a/969667/) too.