# How to get default (vanilla) GNOME shell theme in Ubuntu 18.04 after update?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, themes, gnome-shell

I have updated Ubuntu 18.04 over Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.

How to get default GNOME shell theme in Ubuntu 18.04 after update?

This is that I have now:

[image]

This is that I want to get (black topbar and round corners):

[image]

I've tried all things (from [this post](http://technastic.com/install-stock-gnome-shell-on-ubuntu/)):

```
sudo apt install gnome-session
sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-default-settings
sudo apt install vanilla-gnome-default-settings vanilla-gnome-desktop
sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

It gets default gtk-theme, gdm-theme, icons, but shell theme still from Ubuntu.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969657/how-to-install-the-latest-ubuntu-17-10-shell-theme-under-ubuntu-with-vanilla-gno) also doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you've logged into an (default) Ubuntu session somehow instead of a (vanilla) GNOME session.

To do that when you boot your system and get to the GDM login screen you should find a cogwheel (⚙️) next to the sign in button. If you click on the cogwheel you should find an *GNOME* (and *GNOME on Xorg*) option. Select it and log in.

If you want to adapt [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/969667/480481) from the [post you linked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969657/how-to-install-the-latest-ubuntu-17-10-shell-theme-under-ubuntu-with-vanilla-gno), you need add the following line to the created `gnome-shell.css` file

```
@import url("/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css");
```

**instead of the**

```
@import url("/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css");
```

line.

As suggested by the author of question [@Crantisz](https://askubuntu.com/users/16892/crantisz), to make the topbar always opaque, add the following to the created `gnome-shell.css` file.

```
@import url("/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css");

#panel {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for mentioning `ubuntu.css` as the default Ubuntu theme. I've spent *ages* looking for the file where the default theme comes from.