# Use Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome shell in 18.10

Tags: gnome, 18.04, themes, 18.10

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.10 and wasn't really a fan of the UI changes. I've already reverted the icons and window style using Gnome Tweaks. Now I want to do the same for the shell, but I don't know where I can find the shell theme used in Ubuntu 18.04. How can I revert the Gnome shell so that it looks like it did on Ubuntu 18.04?

Compare the appearance of the top bar on [18.04](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-ecqaBTsGUVg/WuDDGRMv6HI/AAAAAAAAAUo/Fb4eT6HEh6w6cWTLhYhrUlPFx4c0ZogkQCLcBGAs/s1600/ubuntu_1804_screenshots_06_gnome_shell_datetime_notifications.png) and [18.10](https://www.fosslinux.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Yaru-Theme-Menu-Ubuntu-18.04.jpg).

Comment: How does it not look like it did in 18.04 exactly? If you simply set the system theme to _Ambiance_ it should look about the same, AFAIK.

Comment: The top bar and the program launcher on the left. Compare this screenshot of [18.04](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-ecqaBTsGUVg/WuDDGRMv6HI/AAAAAAAAAUo/Fb4eT6HEh6w6cWTLhYhrUlPFx4c0ZogkQCLcBGAs/s1600/ubuntu_1804_screenshots_06_gnome_shell_datetime_notifications.png) with this screenshot of [18.10](https://www.fosslinux.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Yaru-Theme-Menu-Ubuntu-18.04.jpg). Setting the theme to Ambiance makes programs look the same (e.g. my Nautilus now looks how it did on 18.04), but the top bar still looks like 18.10

Comment: I know how to change the shell theme, I just don't know where I can find the 18.04 version of the theme.

Comment: @X-Neon What's the output of `ls /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/` in Terminal?

Comment: I'm away from the PC at the minute, but I'm pretty sure it was `gnome-shell.css gdm3.css` and the `Yaru` folder.

Comment: Try to adapt this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/969667/480481

Comment: Where can I find a copy of the  `ubuntu.css` that was used in 18.04?

Comment: @X-Neon Check if it's there in that directory. Otherwise at the worst case, you can copy it from Ubuntu 18.04 iso. See what happens with the `gnome-shell.css` too.